# can't access to server. Nginx is not working on docker, Django Project, Daphne, Gunicorn, Redis

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose

I am configuring Nginx for ASGI(with Daphne), WSGI(Gunicorn) as well as Redis and Postgres to deploy Django Project.
it was working find but all of sudden the browser is not able to access the server(172.0.0.1:1337) after set up django settings.py for `check --deploy` with following Nginx logs, I don't think it can cause problems because I just added some configurations in local compose file but compose.prod.yml for production.

I didn't set the `.sh` file yet, every pages that I googled for below messages mention those files for running docker-compose in production. would it be a problem not configuring that `.sh` file? but It was working even without the file.

which part should I check for this problem and any configurations that I need to add?

Thanks in advance!
if more information needed, let me know.

```sh
nginx       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx       | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist, exiting
nginx       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

**nginx Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

#########

**EDIT**
** here I changed 2nd line `COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` and now nginx logs display like below**

```sh
nginx       | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx       | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
```

#########

**Nginx.conf**

```
upstream web {
    server web:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}
upstream daphne {
    server daphne:8001 fail_timeout=0;
}


server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://daphne;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /Users/kz/Desktop/projects/community_app/staticfiles/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /Users/kz/Desktop/projects/community_app/media/;
    }

}
```

**docker-compose.prod.yml**

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services: 
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: web
    command: gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes: 
      - static_volume:/address/
      - media_volume:/address/
    expose:
      - 8000
    depends_on: 
      - commu_db
      - redis
    environment: 
      - "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings"
      - "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=##"
  
  daphne:
    build: .
    restart: always
    container_name: daphne
    command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 config.asgi:application
    volumes: 
      - static_volume:/address/
      - media_volume:/address/
    expose:
      - 8001
    # ports: 
    #   - "8001:8001"
    environment: 
      - "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings"
      - "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=###"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - commu_db
      - web

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    volumes: 
      - static_volume:/address/
      - media_volume:/address/
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web
      - daphne
  
  commu_db:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: postgres
    volumes: 
      - postgres_test_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports: 
      - 5433:5432
    environment: 
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres"

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    hostname: comm_redis
    restart: always
    image: redis:5
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    

volumes: 
  postgres_test_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Comment: `COPY nginx.conf` vs `conf.d/default.conf is not a file`

Comment: I still don't get it yet..@Ivan Starostin, I changed that part to `COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` then it shows now this error
`/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version` and still can not access to localhost (localhost:1337)

Comment: Try rephrasing your question as a nginx-only/nginx-docker issue. Django has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I found out that nginx accepts(?) only HTTPS request at the moment from configurations of `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=True` and other things for deployment, I think  I need to look up how to get ssl cert and apply to nginx.conf